# testing user entry on keyup and regex

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my case the requirement is like -

The first name should allow alphabets, some chars like comma, dash and ascent chars.

The code works fine when we try to paste the ascent chars or use "abctajpu" add on in firefox. But as soon as user types in ALT+0192 or any ALT key with num pad.

The keyup function does not work. It lets the user to key in every possible combination with the ALT key.

Here is the sample code..

```
var namePattern = /^[a-zA-Z,-. \'ÀÈÌÒÙàèìòùÁÉÍÓÚÝáéíóúýÂÊÎÔÛâêîôûÃÑÕãñõÄËÏÖÜŸäëïöüŸçÇŠšŽžÅå]$/g;
var negateNamePattern = /[^a-zA-Z,-. \'ÀÈÌÒÙàèìòùÁÉÍÓÚÝáéíóúýÂÊÎÔÛâêîôûÃÑÕãñõÄËÏÖÜŸäëïöüŸçÇŠšŽžÅå]/g;
```

---

```
$("#First_Name").bind('keyup paste altKey', function(event) {
  var obj = $(this);
  if (event.type == 'paste') {
     setTimeout(function() {
         validateRealTime(event, obj, namePattern, negateNamePattern)
     }, 1);
  } else {
   validateRealTime(event, obj, namePattern, negateNamePattern);
  }
});
```

Comment: Nice ASCII Art -
Even if you check what the user enters here, keep in mind to validate the data server-side as well, as javascript-based verfication are easy to bypass.
(ok, I know this won't resolve your problem)

Answer (score 0):

The `key up` event will still be fired when they do any ALT key with num pad, however only when they stop typing will the new character be appended.

Is there a specific reason why you need to do a `key up` event? 
You could validate your field whenever they lose focus on the input.

Also, can we see your `validateRealTime` function?

**EDIT**

I think I've figured out a way to accomplish what you want.

We'll have to change your function to validate a string passed instead of getting the value of the object:

```
function validateRealTime(str, regExPattern, negateRegExPattern) { 
    var fieldVal = str;
    fieldVal = fieldVal.replace(/^(\s+)/g,''); 
    fieldVal = validateInput(fieldVal, regExPattern, negateRegExPattern);  
    // return the new and validated value
    return fieldVal; 
}
```

I've removed the `event` from the function, but you can add it if you are using it somewhere else.

Also, we need to change from a `keyup` to a `keypress` event. This will allow us to determine when the ALT is pressed (ALT + # = one keypress, whereas ALT + # = # keyups)

Futhermore, since the value of the input gets updated on `keyup`, we need to make sure that on `keyup` only the validated string appears.

```
var validatedValue;    // Store validate value to display on 'keyup'
var namePattern = /^[a-zA-Z,-. \'ÀÈÌÒÙàèìòùÁÉÍÓÚÝáéíóúýÂÊÎÔÛâêîôûÃÑÕãñõÄËÏÖÜŸäëïöüŸçÇŠšŽžÅå]$/g;
var negateNamePattern = /[^a-zA-Z,-. \'ÀÈÌÒÙàèìòùÁÉÍÓÚÝáéíóúýÂÊÎÔÛâêîôûÃÑÕãñõÄËÏÖÜŸäëïöüŸçÇŠšŽžÅå]/g;

$("#First_Name").bind('keyup', function(event){
    $(this).val(validatedValue);
})
.bind('keypress paste', function(event){
    var obj = $(this);
    var char;
    var string;
    var newval;


    if (event.type == 'paste'){
         setTimeout(function(){validateRealTime(obj.val(), namePattern, negateNamePattern)}, 1);
    } else {

        // Get the ASCII code of the key pressed and get the Char representation of it
        // When we do an ALT+#, it returns only one ASCII value
        char = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode); 

        // Get the current string and append the character added by the ALT
        // We need to do this, because the val() is not updated yet, it still contains
        //  the old value
        string = obj.val() + char;

        validatedValue= validateRealTime(string, namePattern, negateNamePattern);

    }
});
```

Also, I have not tested the `paste event`.

Comment: We want to remove the unwanted chars a soon as user types in..yes the key up is fired but at last it bypassses all the validations...the function is as follows -                     function validateRealTime(event, obj, regExPattern, negateRegExPattern) {
  var fieldVal = obj.val();
  fieldVal = fieldVal.replace(/^(\s+)/g,'');
  fieldVal = validateInput(fieldVal, regExPattern, negateRegExPattern);
 obj.val(fieldVal);

 }

Comment: I wonder if it would be better to just check each Character instead of the whole string over and over again.

Comment: The logic looks good....but somehow this is not working...it is appending an extra char always and also if i type {} which are not allowed its converting them into ascent char which is valid and printing them.

Comment: is it possible to apply keyup event for all and only when alt key is pressed, keypress event can be applied..

Answer (score 0):

Finally its working....here is the working code...

```
$("#First_Name").bind('keyup paste', function(event){
  var obj = $(this);
  if(event.altKey) {
   $("#First_Name").bind('keypress', function(event){
    setTimeout(function(){validateRealTime(event, obj, namePattern, negateNamePattern)}, 1);
   });
  } else if (event.type == 'paste'){
     setTimeout(function(){validateRealTime(event, obj, namePattern, negateNamePattern)}, 1);
  } else {
   validateRealTime(event, obj, namePattern, negateNamePattern);
  }
    });
```

Thanks a lot for the guidance...the trick was to delay the time so that keyup gets the typed in character.